# An unhandled exception occurred in webdev.webserver.exe

Tags: web, cassini

It happens when I'm trying to open a certain page using it. (Page contains some CSS and JS, nothing really special).
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when disk path passed to the server (the path parameter) contains a double slash. (i.e. `d:\somedir1\\somedir2`)